# How do you make a textview change according to an HTML document on the web

Tags: android, android-layout

A couple of friends and I are setting up a little app business, and we are creating our general app for finding out all the latest news about our other apps. But we have a small problem.

We have a layout xml file with a table row in it. In the table row we want to show two textviews. One that says Current App version (Which we have done successfully) and the other one will show a few numbers from an HTML page which is live now.

I want to know, how would be able to get the text from the HTML document on the Web to that text view, or any other thing we could use.

(We know that the manifest will have to allow the internet)

Thanks

Comment: We want it this way so we can just easily change the HTML document to change the text on the app. So we don't always have to make a new release of the app

Answer (score 0):

So in this TextView, you want to show the content of the HTML page? If this is the case, the best thing you could do is to replace the TextView with a WebView, where you could load the HTML page via its url.

If not this is the case, you can make a GET request to that HTML (i.e. using an Async Task), get the results and present them in the TextView.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I go about setting up a Webview. We had a look at them, but had difficulty setting its URL.
The HTML page is just a very basic document with just a <p> tag

Comment: What problem did you have? It's quite easy indeed. You just call loadUrl in the webview object. For more info please check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Where do I put the WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
???
When I paste it in, it suggests to create a class called webview

Comment: In your layout xml you have to define the WebView, and in your Activity you add this code in order to get access to the WebView and use it.

Comment: When I hover over it, it suggests Create Class webView.class